# Spray HttpClient Synchronous/Blocking Call

Tags: scala, spray

I realize that this may run counter to the purpose of Spray, but I was wondering if when using the HttpClient object, I can make a request block until the result is returned, as opposed to the default behavior of not-blocking and later issuing a callback.

I briefly looked inside the source for HttpClient, thinking it was an akka actor wrapped around a synchronous private http client superclass, but this did not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't the spray HTTP Client just return a scala `Future`?  If so, then you should be able to just do:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import duration._

val fut = ... //call spray here
val result = Await.result(fut, 5 seconds)
```

This will block on the future for up to 5 seconds waiting for it to be completed.  If it times out, an exception will be thrown instead of getting a result.